# Dynamically ceate fields from select Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code that dynamicly create select lists from a select list.

It's working fine, i just need to keep all created select lists shown after a page reload. Now, if i reload the page new select lists disappear.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="selected_form_code">
            <select id="select_btn">
                    <option value="0">--How many rooms ?--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div id="form_submit">
    <!-- Dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates Here -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function get_chambre_html(cn)
{
  return "<div>"
      + "<b>Chambre " + cn + ":</b> "
      + "Adultes: <select id='adultes" + cn + "'>"
      + "<option value='0'>--How many adults ?--</option>"
      + "<option value='1'>1</option>"
      + "<option value='2'>2</option></select>"
      + "<br/>Enfants: <select id='enfants" + cn + "'>"
      + "<option value='0'>--How many enfants ?--</option>"
      + "<option value='1'>1</option>"
      + "<option value='2'>2</option></select>"
      + "<div id='ages" + cn + "'></div>" // empty block for further usage
    +"</div>";
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('select#select_btn').change(function()
  {
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
    $("#form_submit").empty(); //Resetting Form
    // Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically
    create(sel_value);
    // Appending Submit Button To Form
  });


  function create(sel_value)
  {
    for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++)
    {
      $("div#form1").append($("#form_submit").append(get_chambre_html(i)));
      $("div#form1").append($("#form_submit").append("<div id='ages"+i+"'/>"));
      $('select#enfants'+i).change(function(){
        var infants = this.value;
        var i=this.id.substr(7); // 7 = strlen of 'enfants'
        for(var j=0; j<infants; j++)
          $('#ages'+i).append(':[input age block '+i+']: ');
      });
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Of course this will happen. You are populating your list by selecting a value in the dropdown list, and if you reload the page manually you will need to select it again. Anyway your question dosen't show any `html` related page neither how and why you wnat to reload the page.

Comment: This code is in a search form of a result page, so the page is reloaded every search. Is there a solution to save new select lists to show theme after a page reload ? or any alternative to this code to resolve the issue ?

Comment: If you are implementing an hotel reservation system or something like that, it will be better to use `ajax`. You will need to fetch data from the database, save data on it, show results to the users. So trying to reload these values is not useful at all. You will ecounter much more issues while going on with your implementation. So I advise you to make it good from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Before the user leaves/refreshes the page, you can store selections in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem(name, $('#select_btn :selected').val());
}
```

And on page load, you can check to see whether any data has been saved to local storage so you can make sure your page displays what the user had last selected.